# The music is turned off

Tags: sentence-choice

Everyone abruptly stops dancing and the music is turned off.

- Is "the music is turned off" the natural choice or will it sound like the music is already turned off?

Would one of these work better:

The music gets turned off.

The music turns off.

The music stops.

Answer (score 2):

It is correct.

The present tense is an odd choice.  It suggests that you are narrating events as they happen.  It would seem less odd in the past tense, if you are telling a story.

The order suggests that somebody turns off the music after everyone had already stopped dancing.

Answer (score 0):

The second of your choices is a little odd because music cannot perform a physical action, but everyone will understand it, and some will say it.

None of your options, however, solves your problem of specifying the sequence of events.

> Everyone stops dancing, and then the music stops

is clear, succinct, and imparts your intended meaning.